# download attached MS word doc from a XML form

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, perl-module

I am trying to read a XML form using Perl. It is a simple XML form which has some basic information and a MS word doc attachment.

Now I am able to read the XML with XML::Simple module,
but the problem is that the is decoding the file using base64 encode.

I have managed to decode it but not able to save it in MS word doc with the same format. It is showing some unreadable format ans text.
I want to create a MS word doc from this base64 encoded file.
Could you please help me on this ?

Sample XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
    <attached_path>khdgsdybcmnlxkjhdosbduyis/nbjxnciud7djbsjdlagisia/jbkjgdhjsagduysdgisdisodhoishdoi/bcvhgiugudigwyiwyo
        </attached_path>
           </book>

        </catalog>
```

Comment: I don't recognise that encoding. If we could tell what it was, then decoding it is probably pretty easy.

Comment: We could try and guess the encoding of that field. Or you could ask the source of the document what encoding they are using. I suspect the second option will be better.

Comment: How did it happen that they now let you use XML::Simple after you said you cannot use a parser in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31651267/1331451 ?

Comment: On-Topic question: are you allowed to download that document?

Comment: This I had a fight and finally they agree to install this module. Now I am facing another issue. Please check mu question.